# how to study the stability of the fixed point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I wonder how to study the stability of the fixed point of the difference equation $x^{‘}=x\exp{r(1-x)}$

Comment: Is it a difference equation or a differential equation? That makes a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say "fixed point", I am going to assume it is a difference equation. That is, you really mean that you have instead:

$$x_{n+1}=x_ne^{r(1-x_n)} \hspace{5mm}(1)$$

Note how this is different from, say:

$$x'=xe^{r(1-x)} \hspace{5mm}(2)$$

Put simply, $(1)$ is a "discretized" version of $(2)$. It should be then clear that we need different criteria for stability (due to the nature of the equation).

My assumption is based on the fact that you say "fixed points", and technically speaking, you find fixed points of a "map", which is a term given to the R.H.S. of equation $(1)$.

When speaking of differential equations, i.e. $(2)$, you find equilibrium points instead. But let's disregard the technicalities for a minute.

Here are my hints for the first equation $(1)$:

1. Let $f(x):= xe^{r(1-x)}$, i.e the R.H.S. of the equation. Find the points $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=x$. These are your "fixed points". There should be two of them.
2. Evaluate the derivative $f'(x)$ at these fixed points. The criterion for a stable fixed point $x_*$(of a map) is:
   $$ |f'(x_*)| <1$$
3. You will then get a criterion from 2. for the stability of each fixed point in terms of $r$.

Try this and let me know if you get stuck.

By the way, if you meant $(2)$, then the criterion is similar but slightly modified. Here are my hints in that case:

1. Let $f(x):= xe^{r(1-x)}$, i.e the R.H.S. of the equation. Find the points $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=0$. These are your "fixed points". This should be just $x=0$.
2. Evaluate the derivative $f'(x)$ at these fixed points. The criterion for a stable fixed point $x_*$ (for an ODE) is:
   $$ f'(x_*) <0$$
3. You will then get a criterion from 2. for the stability of each fixed point in terms of $r$.